# ASP.NET Web API - If-None-Match Request's header not being read

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, http, asp.net-web-api

I'm having a problem in my application, where the browser is sending me a: `If-None-Match` header, and my server is not being able to fetch it.

Here is my confirmation:

[image: IfNoneMatch not being fetched]

And in here you can see, that, in fact, the header is being sent on the request:

(***"Encabezados de solicitud" is "Request's Headers" in spanish***)

[image: IfNoneMatch is being sent]

Do you guys know what is probably the issue here? I'm out of ideas

---

## Edit

I'm caching my `OkNegotiatedContentResult` in a `MemoryCache` in the server. The `Http Cache` is done afterwards, so it probably fetch the `IHttpActionResult` from the cache.

Therefore, the `RequestMessage` property is from the serialized `IHttpActionResult`.

Maybe, `IfNoneMatch` header is not serializable and therefore it was deserialized as null?.

Can this be confirmed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so, here was the deal.

As I said, I was caching the whole `IHttpActionResult`. This was **WRONG**. Because, that also meant I was caching the `RequestMessage` of that result.

Therefore, when I got the cached `IHttpActionResult` from the memory pool, I got the first `IHttpActionResult` with the **first** request that was cached.

That request may or may not have the `IfNoneMatch` header and is totally different from the browser's request I was inspecting, it was a ***past*** request.